# How to show in angular a dialog as a popver?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

I'm wondering if we are able to do an angular material dialog as a popver. By clicking from a "point" of the view and dialog points over the selected position of a button for example.

This is the angular material dialog current behavior
[image]

This is the behavior I'm looking for.
[image]

Ref: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with MatDialog, but it comes with some setbacks (and it's probably to create a custom pop-over or use one the existing ones).

First of all, you will have to use a set height or width (height if the popover is to be displayed left/right of the button, width if above/below). Alternatively, you can play around with checking the size of the dialog after it was rendered and update the positioning accordingly - that should be doable, but haven't checked on it.

Second, it might be hard to add the "arrow" because of the pre-existing material styling (again, haven't tried it).

What you want to do is get bounding rect of the button and use those values to set the position property on [MatDialogConfig](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig).

Basic implementation (right from button) [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqhk8k). For different positioning adjust the calculations accordingly (should be pretty logical).

Again, I advice looking into Material's [CDK Overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview) and creating your custom component as it will probably save you time in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot open the stackblitz you add. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry about that - updated the link. It's not much, but hopefully will get you in the right direction if you decide to go ahead with the MatDialog route :)